# CORS error on express JS project After deployment

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, cors, backend

I'm getting a 502 error. It's for cors ig. but I tried many ways to fix it. Here's the code :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

// Middleware for parsing JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Enable CORS
app.use(
 cors({
   origin: "https://vibrosonic.onrender.com",
   headers: ["Content-Type"],
   credentials: true,
 })
);
```

And here's my front-end code where I'm fetching my APIs

```
    // Fetch PDF data from the API
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("https://vibrosonic.onrender.com/pdfs")
      .then((response) => {
        setPdfData(response.data.reverse());
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching PDF data:", error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, there is no `headers` configuration for `cors` middleware.

Comment: What error message are you getting, exactly? A `502` status is only problematic in response to a preflight request, but your question doesn't reveal much detail.